# how to drag all items dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my js for dragging and it works for a single element as I expect. But it requires a specific elementID 'myimg'. Actually there will be more elements with the same ID, so how can I drag each of them?

It would be great if you can provide some examples and explain‘em. Thanks in advance!

Here's the code

```
var my_img=document.getElementById("myimg");
var drag_area=document.getElementById("main_area");
my_img.ondragstart=function(evt)
{
    var evt=evt || window.event;
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("text",(evt.clientX-this.offsetLeft)+";"+(evt.clientY-this.offsetTop));
}
drag_area.ondragover=function(evt)
{
    var evt=evt || window.event;
    if(typeof evt.preventDefault=="function")
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        evt.returnValue=false;
    }
}
drag_area.ondragenter=function(evt)
{
    var evt=evt || window.event;
    if(typeof evt.preventDefault=="function")
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        evt.returnValue=false;
    }
}
drag_area.ondrop=function(evt)
{
    var evt=evt || window.event;
    var drag_data=evt.dataTransfer.getData("Text").split(";");
    var offset_x=drag_data[0],
        offset_y=drag_data[1];
    if(typeof evt.preventDefault=="function")
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        evt.returnValue=false;
    }
    my_img.style.left=(evt.clientX-offset_x)+"px";
    my_img.style.top=(evt.clientY-offset_y)+"px";
    console.log(my_img.name);
}
```

`

Comment: Why do you have multiple elements with the same ID? That's not good. Why not use classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it buy using event onDragStart event you will get event target(e.target), store it in a temporary variable and perform whatever action you want to perform and after that set temp variable value to null.

One this is not good in your code is the ID's of elements should be always unique they should not be same. Use classes to select multiple elements together.

This thing won't need any id's and class of element.

```
var temp = null;

onDragStart(e){
 temp = e.target;
 doSomething();
}

doSomething(){
 // your action to perform
 temp = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**

### http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/

**

Sortable — is a JavaScript library for reorderable drag-and-drop lists on modern browsers and touch devices. No jQuery. Supports Meteor, AngularJS, React, Polymer, Knockout and any CSS library, e.g. Bootstrap.